# How can you store 2 pdf files with same name in Azure Blob Storage .dotnet core

Tags: azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

I am creating a web app with C# on dotnet Core, that will ask users to download a pdf document.So i want users to download my pdf so they can fill it and then upload it back on my web site. unfortunately, let's say two users give the same name to they uploaded file, blob storage won't authorize it since it can't have two files with same name. So is there a way to add a GUID to the uploaded file so first of all blob will be happy and i will be able to link the document to the right user

Thanks
Benjamin

Comment: can you provide more details? Which programming language are you using?

Comment: yes sorry it is my first question on stackoverflow, i am not used to it. It is in C# on .dotnet Core. So i want users to download my pdf so they can fill it and then upload it back on my web site. unfortunately, let's say two users give the same name to they uploaded file, blob storage won't authorize it since it can't have two files with same name. So is there a way to add a GUID to the uploaded file so first of all blob will be happy and i will be able to link the document to the right user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just append a guid to the blob name:

```
string blobName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```